# Strange stuff into Accept-Language header starting with x-ns

Tags: proxy, http, squid, http-headers

We are getting this kind of HTTP header:

```
Accept-Language: fr-CH,x-ns1Ci7OslejNxN,x-ns2af6MxcVGQb2
```

Can anyone help me knowing where does it come from. It's just by curiosity that I'm asking this. Searching around, I suspect a Squid proxy but I'd love having a full explanation.

Comment: Please provide the full HTTP headers for one of these requests - it might then be possible to see what's going on.

Comment: @RichVel Right! I'll start logging all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Looks odd, it might be that this is a hack attempt, similar to [this one](http://tomcat.apache.org/security-6.html#Fixed_in_Apache_Tomcat_6.0.6) - however you'd need to provide more log information.  Worth looking at your logs, and checking the web apps you have on that server for any vulnerabilities in this area.

Comment: These requests seem legit: `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)` and the cookie contains some Google Analytics (`__utm*`) stuff too. Other browsers do that too (Firefox, …)

Comment: A link I just found on how these kind of breach can be used: http://programmingpanda.blogspot.com/2009/08/xss-in-http-headers-accept-language.html